# Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate exception while running Cucumber tests with Springs

Tags: spring, gradle, java-8, cucumber, junit4

I'm trying to integrate cucumebr tests with Springs. I have created class named `MyClass` under package `actions` with Spring annotation `@Component`

```
package actions;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyClass{
public void printSomething(){
    System.out.println("Print this);
}
```

Created `AppConfig` class with Spring Annotation `@ComponentScan`. And passed package created above `(actions)` into`@ComponentScan`

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"actions"})
public class AppConfig {

}
```

In my gluecode, i initialised `MyClass` Using `@Autowired`

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes=AppConfig.class)
public StepDefinitions implements En{

    @Autowired private MyClass myClass;

    public StepDefinitions(){   
        Before(() -> {
            myClass.printSomething();           
        });
```

Below is my cucumber test runenr class

```
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
              features = "myfeature.feature"
              ,glue={"stepDefinitions"}
              )
@ContextConfiguration(classes=AppConfig.class)
public class TestRunner{

}
```

When i run the TestRunner as junit Test, junit throwing following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate [class org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.createCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate(BootstrapUtils.java:103)
    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.createBootstrapContext(BootstrapUtils.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:124)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.spring.CucumberTestContextManager.<init>(SpringFactory.java:206)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.spring.SpringFactory.start(SpringFactory.java:102)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.buildWorld(JavaBackend.java:123)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.buildBackendWorlds(Runtime.java:141)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:38)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:102)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:95)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:38)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:761)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:207)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.createCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate(BootstrapUtils.java:100)
    ... 32 more
```

and eclipse console printing below message

```
[DEBUG] Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
```

I'm using gradle as build tool. Following are the list of dependencies i added

```
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring', version: '2.5.6'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aop', version: '5.0.7.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aspects', version: '5.0.7.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-beans', version: '5.0.7.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '5.0.7.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context-support', version: '5.0.7.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: '5.0.7.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-expression', version: '5.0.7.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-instrument', version: '5.0.7.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-instrument-tomcat', version: '4.3.18.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version: '5.0.7.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jms', version: '5.0.7.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-messaging', version: '5.0.7.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version: '5.0.7.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-oxm', version: '5.0.7.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version:'5.0.7.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-tx', version:'5.0.7.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version:'5.0.7.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version:'5.0.7.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc-portlet', version: '4.3.18.RELEASE'
```

Could anyone tell me the issue causing the exception. Are there any **dependencies** i need to include or is there any **specific runner** i should use to invoke `cucumber-junit` in springs other than `Cucumber.class`

Comment: I tried giving @ContextConfiguration(classes=AppConfig.class) only in StepDefinitions.java class and only  in TestRunenr.java class and also tried giving in both these classes. Getting same exception everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing unwanted dependencies from gradle build resolved the issue for me. Nothing wrong in the code.

Just added below dependencies and removed all.

```
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '5.0.7.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: '5.0.7.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version:'5.0.7.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-tx', version:'5.0.7.RELEASE'
```

Answer (score 1):

I just change my **pom.xml**, and remove the version from *org.springframework* then run, it worked perfectly

```
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

**Yahoo!! Great**

**Note:** SNAPSHOT, M1, M2, M3, and M4 releases typically WORK IN PROGRESS. The Spring team is still working on them, Recommend NOT using them.